# toggle inline styles with JQuery - display & overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you please take a look at my code:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

I need to toggle this style when we clicked again on `.button`. That should be look like:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/bxe7fojn/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [JQuery's toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Create those 2 classes which I did in my example as `.display-show` & `.body-show`

Try this:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
        $("#overlay").toggleClass('display-show');
        $('body').toggleClass('body-show');
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  }

#overlay {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
  
.display-show {
  display: none;
  }
  
.body-show {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**Update 1**: (according to your jsfiddle)

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
        $("#overlay").toggleClass('display-show');
        $('body').toggleClass('body-show');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 1500px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#overlay {

  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.display-show {
  display: block !important;
}

.body-show {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: upvote for using classes, which - in general - is a much better approach than inline styles.

Comment: In this case I need to use inline styling.

Comment: @vishnu its not inline styling, its calling an externally styled class. I've shown it with your codes from jsfiddle , see Update 1 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code?
(Runnable example : https://codepen.io/hoge1e3/pen/mddbJPV)

```
var overlayVisible=false;
$(".button").click(function () {
    if (!overlayVisible) {
      $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
      $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
      overlayVisible=true;
    } else {
      $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
      $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
      overlayVisible=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have using this now:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#overlay').toggle();
    if ($("#overlay").is(':visible')) {
        $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    }
    else {
        $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
        $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
});
```